# Create Multiple List Items with One Function

Tags: javascript, caml, client-object-model

Is it possible to create multiple list items with one function in JavaScript / ECMAScript?  I know that a single item can be created with the code below, but would like to know if it is possible to use a loop or something to create multiple list items rather than calling the function over and over.

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function createListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
    oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since CSOM is [request batching process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx), you could prepare multiple ListItem objects and then create all of them with a single query.

The code below demonstrates how create multiple tasks:

```
function createListItems(listTitle,itemsProperties,OnItemsAdded,OnItemsError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

    var items = [];
    $.each(itemsProperties, function (i, itemProperties) {

       var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
       var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
       for(var propName in itemProperties) {
          listItem.set_item(propName, itemProperties[propName]) 
       }
       listItem.update();
       context.load(listItem);
       items.push(listItem);

    });

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemsAdded(items);           
        },
        OnItemsError
    );
}



//Usage
var tasksProperties = [{'Title':'Approval','Body':'Planned Purchase Orders Approval'},
                       {'Title':'Aggrement','Body':'Contract Purchase Agreements Approval'}];


createListItems('Tasks',tasksProperties,
     function(items){
           console.log('Tasks have been created successfully');
     },
     function(sender,args){
          console.log('Error occured while creating tasks:' + args.get_message());
     }
);
```